# showing slack bot as writing status while processing

Tags: python, slack-api

I am writing a slack bot using the python sdk.

Until now, everything is doing well but I would like to make a improvement,
Some processing are quite long running, so when my bot is 'thinking' I would like to see the bot 'as ...writing'

I am using the following code:
``` client.chat_postMessage(channel=channel_id, text=line) ````
How can I set the 'is writing' status waiting the line to be ready to be written

Thank you